# probability, electric circuit, a problem

Tags: probability

In the circuit shown below, if any switch is six times as likely to be closed as it is to be open what is the probability of a closed path between a and b? I am completely unaware of how to solve this problem, Thanks for helping.

[image]

Comment: Either use inclusion/exclusion (at least one of the switches is closed) or the complementary probability (it is not the case that all switches are open).

Comment: I don't understand, could you please be more specific?